# not properly displaying the Bar chart using coldFusion

Tags: coldfusion, bar-chart, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-10

I am facing a problem with a bar chart using ColdFusion.

If there is only one `<cfchartseries>` tag, then the SeriesLabel attribute is not displaying. Instead of that, the items of the cfchartdata are displaying.
If there are more then one `<cfchartseries>`, then the SeriesLabel specified is displaying properly.

Please look at the code and its corresponding bar chart attached .

**BarChart1:**

```
<cfchart format="jpg" xaxistitle="Month" yaxistitle="MonthlyTotal" 
       seriesPlacement="stacked"    
       showLegend="yes" 
       showMarkers="no" 
       chartHeight="300" chartWidth="400" >
    <labelStyle orientation="Horizontal"/>
    <cfchartseries type="bar" seriesLabel="T"  >
        <cfchartdata item="jan2007" value="1">
        <cfchartdata item="Feb2007" value="3">
        <cfchartdata item="Mar2007" value="2">
        <cfchartdata item="Apr2007" value="4">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

[image: BarChart1]

**BarChart2 :**

```
<cfchart format="jpg" xaxistitle="Month" yaxistitle="MonthlyTotal" 
    seriesPlacement="stacked"    
    showLegend="yes" 
    showMarkers="no" 
    chartHeight="300" chartWidth="400" >

    <labelStyle orientation="Horizontal"/>
    <cfchartseries type="bar" seriesLabel="T"  >
        <cfchartdata item="jan2007" value="1">
        <cfchartdata item="Feb2007" value="3">
        <cfchartdata item="Mar2007" value="2">
        <cfchartdata item="Apr2007" value="4">
    </cfchartseries>
    <cfchartseries type="bar"  seriesLabel="D">
        <cfchartdata item="jan2007" value="1">
        <cfchartdata item="Feb2007" value="3">
        <cfchartdata item="Mar2007" value="2">
        <cfchartdata item="Apr2007" value="4">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

[image: BarChart2]

The Barchart1 needs to show `T` as the SeriesLabel. Instead of that, its showing the "nonths", which are the X-axis variables. The Barchart2 is showing properly as per the code.

I tried my best to solve it by my self but I am unable to find the problem. Requesting people give me your ideas. I am waiting for you suggestions.

Thank You

Comment: `its corresponding bar chart attached` - where?

Comment: @duncan: for one "cfchartseries" "seriesLabel" not showing.here is the attached chart:
1.http://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/1085d1204209795/barchart1.jpg
2.http://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/1086d1204209842/barchart2.jpg

Comment: The screenshots have a watermark that says "ColdFusion MX 7", yet you question lists CF 8, CF 9, and CF 10. The charting engine changed in 10. I wonder what version you are really working with

Comment: @James A Mohler: Currently iam wprking on CF 10. i have attached screenshot for example.the same problem i have facing in my chart for only one tiem like "BarChart1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to put Texas on top, you could use chartTitle instead. I'd also strongly urge you to consider using the newer chart engine if you are CF10 Enterprise, or another chart engine altogether.

Comment: chartTitle is a property of cfchart.

Comment: how to put title can u explane?

Comment: Are you asking how to use it? Um - just title="something"